# Issue when adding product description at WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I'm trying to display the product description at WooCommerce checkout.

I'm using:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_product_description_2', 10, 2 );
function wc_checkout_product_description_2( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  $post_data->post_excerpt );
    return $other_data;
}
```

---

It takes the product short description and displays it below the product.

It almost works perfectly, but it displays a colon (:) at the end of the description and the colon remains even if there is no short description.

Result:

[image]

---

I can't figure out why it appears any how to get rid of it. I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon is automatically added to the key. Because you only use `name`, this will be added at the end of the product description.

To display this correctly, you can use:

```php
// Display on cart & checkout pages
function filter_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    // Product excerpt
    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty( $post_excerpt ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Product description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'   => $post_excerpt,
            'display' => $post_excerpt,
        );
    }
    
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

---

OR if you really want to remove the colon/name (key). In addition to using the filter hook with code from my answer, you will also have to overwrite the [cart/cart-item-data.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php) template file

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-item-data.php`.

Replace

```php
<dl class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
        <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

With

```
<dl class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dt>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Comment: Hi @7uc1f3r, thank you for your answer. I used the code snippet you suggested and then simply hid the "**Product description**" text with CSS: `td.product-name dl.variation dt {display: none;}`.